# Python - Aggregate by month and calculate average

Tags: python, date, csv, pandas, aggregate

I have a csv which looks like this:

```
Date,Sentiment
2014-01-03,0.4
2014-01-04,-0.03
2014-01-09,0.0
2014-01-10,0.07
2014-01-12,0.0
2014-02-24,0.0
2014-02-25,0.0
2014-02-25,0.0
2014-02-26,0.0
2014-02-28,0.0
2014-03-01,0.1
2014-03-02,-0.5
2014-03-03,0.0
2014-03-08,-0.06
2014-03-11,-0.13
2014-03-22,0.0
2014-03-23,0.33
2014-03-23,0.3
2014-03-25,-0.14
2014-03-28,-0.25
etc
```

And my goal is to aggregate date by months and calculate average of months. Dates might not start with 1. or January. Problem is that I have a lot of data, that means I have more years. For this purpose I would like to find the soonest date (month) and from there start counting months and their averages. For example:

```
Month count, average
1, 0.4 (<= the earliest month)
2, -0.3
3, 0.0
...
12, 0.1
13, -0.4 (<= new year but counting of month is continuing)
14, 0.3
```

I'm using Pandas to open csv

```
data = pd.read_csv("pks.csv", sep=",")
```

so in `data['Date']` I have dates and in `data['Sentiment']` I have values. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably the simplest approach is to use the `resample` command. First, when you read in your data make sure you parse the dates and set the date column as your index (ignore the `StringIO` part and the header=True ... I am reading in your sample data from a multi-line string):

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),header=True,parse_dates=['Date'],
                     index_col='Date')
>>> df

            Sentiment
Date
2014-01-03       0.40
2014-01-04      -0.03
2014-01-09       0.00
2014-01-10       0.07
2014-01-12       0.00
2014-02-24       0.00 
2014-02-25       0.00
2014-02-25       0.00
2014-02-26       0.00
2014-02-28       0.00
2014-03-01       0.10
2014-03-02      -0.50
2014-03-03       0.00
2014-03-08      -0.06
2014-03-11      -0.13
2014-03-22       0.00
2014-03-23       0.33
2014-03-23       0.30
2014-03-25      -0.14
2014-03-28      -0.25


>>> df.resample('M').mean()

            Sentiment
2014-01-31      0.088
2014-02-28      0.000
2014-03-31     -0.035
```

And if you want a month counter, you can add it after your `resample`:

```
>>> agg = df.resample('M',how='mean')
>>> agg['cnt'] = range(len(agg))
>>> agg

            Sentiment  cnt
2014-01-31      0.088    0
2014-02-28      0.000    1
2014-03-31     -0.035    2
```

You can also do this with the `groupby` method and the `TimeGrouper` function (group by month and then call the mean convenience method that is available with `groupby`).

```
>>> df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).mean()

            Sentiment
2014-01-31      0.088
2014-02-28      0.000
2014-03-31     -0.035
```

Comment: using new syntax for resample; `df.resample('M').mean()`

Comment: if the date is not in index rather as a column and the column name is "date", then `df.resample('M', on="date").mean()`

Answer (score 7):

To get the monthly average values of a Data Frame when the DataFrame has daily data rows 'Sentiment', I would:

1. Convert the column with the dates , `df['dates']` into the index of the DataFrame `df`: `df.set_index('date',inplace=True)`
2. Then I'll convert the index `dates` into a month-index: `df.index.month`
3. Finally I'll calculate the mean of the DataFrame  **GROUPED BY MONTH**: `df.groupby(df.index.month).Sentiment.mean()`

I go slowly throw each step here:

#### Generation DataFrame with dates and values

- You need first to import Pandas and Numpy, as well as the module `datetime`

  ```
  from datetime import datetime
  ```
- Generate a Column `'date'` between 1/1/2019 and the 3/05/2019, at week 'W' intervals. And a column `'Sentiment'`with random values between 1-100:

  ```
  date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='3/05/2018', freq='W')
  df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
  df['Sentiment']=np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng)))
  ```
- the `df` has two columns `'date'` and `'Sentiment'`:

  ```
          date  Sentiment
  0 2018-01-07         34
  1 2018-01-14         32
  2 2018-01-21         15
  3 2018-01-28          0
  4 2018-02-04         95
  5 2018-02-11         53
  6 2018-02-18          7
  7 2018-02-25         35
  8 2018-03-04         17
  ```

  #### Set `'date'`column as the index of the DataFrame:

  ```
  df.set_index('date',inplace=True)
  ```
- `df` has one column `'Sentiment'` and the index is  `'date'`:

  ```
              Sentiment
  date                 
  2018-01-07         34
  2018-01-14         32
  2018-01-21         15
  2018-01-28          0
  2018-02-04         95
  2018-02-11         53
  2018-02-18          7
  2018-02-25         35
  2018-03-04         17
  ```

#### Capture the month number from the index

```
    months=df.index.month
```

#### Obtain the mean value of each month grouping by month:

```
    monthly_avg=df.groupby(months).Sentiment.mean()
```

#### The mean of the dataset by month `'monthly_avg'` is:

```
    date
    1    20.25
    2    47.50
    3    17.00
```